# can you help for diagram for in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

```
\begin{tikzcd}
3 \arrow[dr] & \\
4 \arrow[r] & 2\arrow[dr] & \\
1
\end{tikzcd}
```

[image]

could you help me? how do yo writting latex?

Comment: I see you've asked some questions about similar diagrams before, are you able to do any part of this yourself? Where does the problem lie, exactly?

Comment: the direction of the arrows and the writing of numbers. i can't get the image i want

Comment: Then show us the code with what you have achieved so far.

Comment: all I did was faulty,

Comment: So? Usually a question saying "I have this code that does this, but I want to get the output shown in this image, what do I have to change" is better than "what code do I need to reproduce this image".

Answer (score 6):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}     
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
3 \arrow[rd] &  &  \\
4 \arrow[r] &
\begin{array}{c}
2\\
3\  4
\end{array}   
\arrow[rd] &  \\
 &  & 
 \begin{array}{c}
1\\
2\\
3\ 4
\end{array}   
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, yes, but how can I write these numbers a little closer?

Answer (score 6):

You can set the numbers in an array, but in `\footnotesize`, with reduced interline spacing. Better to define a suitable command for it.

With `between origins`, the south-east bound arrows will be aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\stack}[1]{%
  \mbox{%
    \footnotesize
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.75}%
    $\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{array}$%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep={4em,between origins},column sep={4em,between origins}]
\stack{3} \arrow[dr] \\
\stack{4} \arrow[r] &
\stack{2\\3\;4} \arrow[dr] \\
&& \stack{1\\2\\3\;4}
\end{tikzcd}
\qquad
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep={4em,between origins},column sep={4em,between origins}]
\stack{1\\2\\3} \arrow[dr] \\
\stack{1\\2\\4} \arrow[r] &
\stack{1\\2} \arrow[dr] \\
&& \stack{1}
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want Times-like fonts, use `newtx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz-cd}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\tikzcdset{arrow style=math font}

\newcommand{\stack}[1]{%
  \mbox{%
    \footnotesize
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.75}%
    $\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{array}$%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep={4em,between origins},column sep={4em,between origins}]
\stack{3} \arrow[dr] \\
\stack{4} \arrow[r] &
\stack{2\\3\;4} \arrow[dr] \\
&& \stack{1\\2\\3\;4}
\end{tikzcd}
\qquad
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep={4em,between origins},column sep={4em,between origins}]
\stack{1\\2\\3} \arrow[dr] \\
\stack{1\\2\\4} \arrow[r] &
\stack{1\\2} \arrow[dr] \\
&& \stack{1}
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Your picture seems to have been produced with Xy-pic (but the quality is inferior and the arrow tips very ugly).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\newcommand{\stack}[1]{%
  \mbox{%
    \footnotesize
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.75}%
    $\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{array}$%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix@R-1pc{
  \stack{3} \ar[dr] \\
  \stack{4} \ar[r] &
  \stack{2\\3\;4} \ar[dr] \\
  && \stack{1\\2\\3\;4}
}
\qquad
\xymatrix@R-1pc{
  \stack{1\\2\\3} \ar[dr] \\
  \stack{1\\2\\4} \ar[r] &
  \stack{1\\2} \ar[dr] \\
  && \stack{1}
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excuse me very much for my opinion. Please can you add the same example with `Xy-pic`. Peraphs with `newtxmath` and `\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}` the result is the same of the picture?

Comment: @Sebastiano Added